# Cannot deserialize string from BsonType ObjectId in MongoDb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am getting error `"Cannot deserialize string from BsonType ObjectId"` while trying to get all the record from MongoDb in C# WebAPI

My Id is

```
[BsonId]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

After Changing it to

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
public string Id { get; set; }
```

its working fine

But while i'm calling post method, its giving me different error

```
"'d05e139c-3a48-4213-bd89-eba0c22c3c6f' is not a valid 24 digit hex string."
```

How can solve this problem

My Model is:

```
public class EstablishmentDetails
{

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentName { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentType { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public Int32 PIN { get; set; }
    public Int64 PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

My repository fro Get method

```
public IEnumerable<EstablishmentDetails> GetAllEstablishmentDetails()
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(mCollection.Count()) > 0)
        {
            var EstablishmentDetailsCollection = mCollection.FindAllAs(typeof(EstablishmentDetails));

            if (EstablishmentDetailsCollection.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (EstablishmentDetails item in EstablishmentDetailsCollection)
                {
                    establishmentDetails.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        var results = establishmentDetails.AsQueryable();
        return results;
    }
```

My repository for Post method

```
public EstablishmentDetails Add(EstablishmentDetails ed)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ed.Id))
        {
            ed.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        mCollection.Save(ed);
        return ed;
    }
```

Comment: I think your question includes an answer to the question of many people ;) (`BsonRepresentation`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of using

```
ed.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

I used

```
ed.Id = MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
```

For generating Id

Its working fine : )

Comment: This is worked like a charm.!

Answer (score 2):

Guid.NewGuid() will not produce ObjectId.
Object Id is 12 byte data structure and Guid produce 16byte hex string (without '-')

You should remove attribute `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]`

You can use any string as Id in your entity for example 'HiDude' and any string in utf8 format.