# Can't deserialize from ObjectId to String in a MongoDb collection query

Tags: c#, mongodb, casting, mongodb-.net-driver

Whenever I am trying to get a list of Ids from a collection:

```
var messages = db.GetCollection<MessageExchange>(collectionName);
var ids = messages
   .AsQueryable()
   .Where(_=> true)
   .Select(x => x.Id)
   .ToList();
```

I am getting a cast error:

> System.FormatException   HResult=0x80131537   Message=Cannot
>   deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'ObjectId'.   Source=   StackTrace:

I am not able to modify the definition of a class, because its implemented in a package I can't change. Therefore the solution of putting:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
```

on it, is ***not possible***. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868367/1257607).

Is it possible to cast this in the Linq query?

Comment: Do you want a List of strings or a list of object id(s) ?

Comment: just need a list of the ids, better if they are strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because `db.GetCollection<MessageExchange>` defines the collection as strongly typed objects which the driver will process in combination with any further logic that is carried out (using linq or otherwise).

Your best options would be either:

1. Define a class which is compatible with your Mongo Collection in your own code, then use that class to deserialise your results `db.GetCollection<MyCustomMessageExchange>` which  you can then use with your linq query above to select just the ids.
2. Just use the default `BsonDocument` to define your collection and use a projection:
   `db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>.Find(new BsonDocument()).Project("{_id: 1}").ToList()`

Comment: I like option 2! Didn't think of that. That would cause the least amount of overhead in the codebase.

Comment: @cl0ud - option 2 updated, I forgot to include `.Find()`

Comment: I just implemented it with this code: `var myIds = db
                    .GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName)
                    .Find(_ => true)
                    .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("_id"))
                    .ToList();`
this is working and creating elements like this: {{ "_id" : "cc969282-c9d2-4cba-a776-d79ff1274d56" }}

Answer (score 2):

You are by no means bound to using whats in the package - if you know what the definition is of the class I would suggest rolling your own `MessageExchange` inside your project and using that to query the collection using the driver.

This allows you also to only get fields that you need(using `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` attribute on your new class) and not what the author of the package forces on you .

If using the type `MessageExchange` is absolutely necessary for your program flow and structure Id suggest using something like AutoMapper to cast back to the original type from your own one.

Comment: could you please elaborate the use of automapper?

Comment: @DanielV automapper allows you create a relation between two models. So you dont have to do the messy `new MessageExchange() ` and assigning the properties manually. You can simply do `var messageExchange = mapper.Map<MessageExchange>(yourNewMessageExchangeObject);`

Comment: I understand, I am exploring @steveland approach to something completely independent, because what I need is the "ids" don't care about the objects actually

Comment: @DanielV I would definitely go with option 2 of Steves answer!

Answer (score 1):

The [ObjectId structure](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId.htm) implements a [ToString](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId_ToString.htm) method, allowing you to convert the object into its string representation.

So I think you can do:

```
var messages = db.GetCollection<MessageExchange>(collectionName);
var ids = messages
   .AsQueryable()
   .Where(_=> true)
   .Select(x => x.Id.ToString())
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Steves approach seems to the right one, thank you for your response.